# SSMS Missing Index Report

Tags: ssms

A colleague has screenshotted the Missing Index Report from SQL Server Management Stuido, but cannot tell me how to access this myself!!

I've scanned through the "Reports" menus by right clicking various items in SSMS and googled, but can't seem to find out where to open this report.

Can you help?

[image: Missing Index Report]

SQL Server Management Studio                        15.0.18206.0

Answer (score 5):

In SSMS right click the server, Reports->Performance Dashboard.

Bottom right of the page is a box headed Miscellaneous Information

A link Missing Indexes will take you there.

Long winded but it works for me. If you find a more direct method, please let me know.